# Can you develop for Azure with .NET using osx now?

Tags: macos, azure

Is it now possible to develop applications using .NET core on a OSX or are there limitations?

How can you develop using .NET core when SQL server will not run on a Mac?

Answer (score 0):

You can develop .NET applications using Visual Studio Code and other development tools like Sharp Develop + Mono.

Eventually Mysql will come up with .NET core driver [pretty soon](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/05/16/announcing-entity-framework-core-rc2/), MySQL already has mono driver. So you will not miss much, by the time you will get your hands on .NET core on OSX, MySQL or some other alternative will be available.

Though it will not be that great experience, better alternative would be to fire up a windows vm inside Virtual Box or Parallel and use all windows based tools. You can easily run windows server core with SQL Server.

Comment: I already have .net core installed, it took 5 minutes.  I can't wait for a driver to be developed.  So the answer is not yet.